# NCrunch build fails, starting with fody >= 4.0.0 "Cannot convert transparent proxy to IInnerWeaver"

Tags: c#, fody, ncrunch

I have the following error while building my projects using NCrunch.

```
Fody: An unhandled exception occurred:
Exception:
Der transparente Proxy kann nicht in den Typ "IInnerWeaver" umgewandelt werden.
Type:
System.InvalidCastException
StackTrace:
   bei Processor.ExecuteInOwnAssemblyLoadContext()
   bei Processor.Inner()
   bei Processor.Execute()
Source:
Fody
TargetSite:
Void ExecuteInOwnAssemblyLoadContext()
```

It took me a while to determin **howto reproduce the error:**

Create a new c# library (net472) and install the nuget package **NullGuard.Fody (1.8.7)** which has a dependency to **Fody (>= 3.3.5)**. Do not use packages.conf, but the new PackageReference format. Add FodyWeavers.xml.

Activate NCrunch (3.26.0.4 in Visual Studio 2019) using these settings:

- Allow parallel execution
- Run all tests automatically
- Do not ignore tests by default

Both, Visual Studio and NCrunch can sucessfully build the project.

Install **Fody (4.0.0)**, now, NCrunch cannot build any more, but Visual Studio still can.

Is this a fody/ncrunch bug, or do I miss something?

Comment: you are using a very old version of fody. does the same problem exist in version 5.0.3?

Comment: Yes, the problem is present even in 5.0.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed in version 5.0.5 of Fody  https://github.com/Fody/Fody/milestone/109

Comment: Thank you for this very quick bug-fix. Strange, that nobody has detected it up until now.

Comment: @sa.he BTW id you are using Fody you and your company should be patrons https://github.com/Fody/Home/blob/master/pages/licensing-patron-faq.md